# javascript: submit form in an iframe...help

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, submit, lightbox

I can't believe I've never done this before....

Here's my situation:  I am using 2 jQuery plugins.  Shadowbox and validate (bassistance).

I click on a link to sign up for a newsletter.  The link opens a form in a shadowbox.  No biggie.  The form is validated with the plugin.

When the form is validated and ready to submit, it doesn't.

This is what my submitHandler option (in the validate plugin) looks like:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

form.submit();

var s = window.parent.Shadowbox;
s.open({
player:     'iframe',
title:      'Thank you!',
content:    'http://www.somesite.com/includes/thank_you_grid_3.php',
width:      270,
height:     110
});
}
```

Help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I've used a [hidden iframe for uploads](http://www.joshclarkson.net/blog/file-uploads-in-a-hidden-iframe-using-jquery/) before.

Answer (score 0):

If your form has a submit button with name of 'submit' as well, it won't submit programmatically. Well, at least in some browsers.

Who knows why?.. Comment please ;)