# Researching: Form targeting an iFrame to submit

Tags: html, ajax, forms, file-upload

I initially set out to learn how to handle "ajax-ready file uploads"; I found, and comprehend, one of the main concepts: it's not possible as ajax, but you can submit a form with the target set to a hidden iFrame's id *[1]*.  That *seems* to be generally accepted by the community and compatible with all browsers.  Is that an accurate assessment?

My question is: what are the pitfalls to this approach?  Because if there are none, it seems to me that every "ajax-ready post" could be done in this same fashion.  Remove the file upload component and this approach versus, say, a `jQuery.post()` approach appear to have identical outcomes.

In all the questions and resources I've researched, I've only been able to find "solutions" for handling my initial issue.  I've been unable to find any sort of "pro v. con list" or "pitfalls to this approach" anywhere regarding a form targeting an iFrame; if you know of one, please feel free to share it!

*[1]* HTML Example:

```
<form method="post" target="take_the_reload">
    ...
</form>
<iframe class="hide_me" id="take_the_reload" name="take_the_reload"></iframe>
```

Much obliged,

Beez

References: Just a couple of the resources I've used:

1. http://www.joshclarkson.net/blog/file-uploads-in-a-hidden-iframe-using-jquery/
2. [Firefox form targetting an iframe is opening new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083325/firefox-form-targetting-an-iframe-is-opening-new-tab)
3. http://terminalapp.net/submitting-a-form-with-target-set-to-a-script-generated-iframe-on-ie/
4. [javascript: submit form in an iframe...help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478525/javascript-submit-form-in-an-iframe-help)
5. http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first started AJAX (before jQuery and Prototype came along) I used to do exactly that with all my forms....just post them to a hidden Iframe. It was easy and painless.

The drawbacks of form-post:

- It's not really "pure" AJAX (file uploads aside). I'm sure all the DOM manipulation in the iframe for the result is slower than just getting back a response via XHR.
- The error handling is more difficult - you have to look at what the server puts in the Iframe as a result
- Things are moving towards JSON-based data handling which forms alone don't do
- Sometimes you want to do something "in the middle" between the form and the server such as some field mapping or including other client-side data

Comment: Excellent info! With JavaScript, we can handle "pre-processing" of the form 'onclick' of the submit button, the caveat being the form itself needs to be manipulated with required changes (e.g., hidden fields) before a `return true;` can be done to send the form off to iFrame-land.  But the result of the action can still be JSON and the body of the iFrame would be the JSON text (is that a big deal?). JSON response errors can be handled with something like: `{errorNo: 1, errorText: 'oops!'}`? Forms themselves are always going to be sent as params (no way to send JSON to the server, is there?).

Comment: I'm not sure how you would retrieve a JSON result in an Iframe since you don't really have a DOM in there. You probably can. I've never tried.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but let's say in php if you echo'd `{errorNo: 1, errorText: 'oops!'}`, that's all that would be on the page, I think.  Retrieving that seems like it's just be a matter of using firebug to inspect the dom?  Well, this gives me enough to try.  Thanks for the response!